# String not passed correctly from C# console application to VBS

Tags: c#, variables, batch-file, vbscript

I have a VBS script that plays a sound file at whichever directory is passed to it. Here is the script:

```
Dim oPlayer
Set oPlayer = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")
oPlayer.URL = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
oPlayer.controls.play 
While oPlayer.playState <> 1 ' 1 = Stopped
  WScript.Sleep 100
Wend
oPlayer.close
```

This is the C# script i use to call the VBS:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"myscript.vbs", "mydir\0.mp3");
```

I also tried:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"myscript.vbs", @"mydir\0.mp3");
```

The script cannot play/find the sound file. I get the error "Cannot play file with unknown extension". However, it works perfectly fine when I call the VBS with a batch file:

```
cscript myscript.vbs mydir\0.mp3
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: If the real `mydir` or `0` filename contain spaces you'll need to quote the path `"\"mydir\\0.mp3\""`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After messing around for a while, I have identified the problem: the VBS script wasn't executed from the directory I wanted it to. The fix was simple: instead of using a relative directory, I passed it the full path:

```
C:\something\mydir\0.mp3
```